# Extract POST data and create a model object - Django

Tags: python, django

What I want to do: is do my `get_initial()` to create a Author object with defaults, then extract data from Post.
Conceptually, code does it right, but in reality initial doesnt return and object doesnt creates

````
```
class StartGame(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Author```

    fields = {'date_of_death'}

    permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
    def get_initial(self,req):
        initial = super(StartGame, self).get_initial()
        initial = initial.copy()
        return initial
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        bb_object = BigBlind.objects.create(bb_sum=request.POST.get('bigblind'))
        bb_object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('catalog:index'))
````

If I delete my post method, my object creates fine, but I need to create BigBlind object too, I just dont get how to do it.
Or what should I read exactly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dealed: created model in Post method, delete get_initial_data